# MVC 5 Html helper CheckBoxFor cannot be selected in Razor partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, checkboxfor

So I've been given html from a digital agency that I need to convert to MVC.  I understand that the Html.CheckboxFor(..) creates an additional hidden input field to capture non selection of the checkbox as false.

However on my page I can't select my checkbox.  If I delete the `<input type="hidden....>` in Firebug I can select the checkbox.  (As in I can't click on the checkbox and make it selected visually)

The generated html is:

(html provided to me)

```
<div class="terms well">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="authorize" name="authorize">
            <span class="checkbox-display"><span class="checkbox-display-inner fa fa-check"></span></span>
            <span class="checkbox-label">I accept full responsibility for the information I provide on this form.</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

(html generated by the html helper - I haven't bothered trying to use the label for as I'm not sure the styling will still work).

```
<div class="terms well">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="AuthorisePayment" id="AuthorisePayment"><input type="hidden" value="false" name="AuthorisePayment">
            <span class="checkbox-display"><span class="checkbox-display-inner fa fa-check"></span></span>
            <span class="checkbox-label terms-credit" style="display: inline-block;">I accept full responsibility for information and authorisations I provide on this form.</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone got any ideas?  I'm not 100% what to include in this post to help find the answer.

The razor view contains:

```
<div class="terms well">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AuthorisePayment)
            <span class="checkbox-display"><span class="checkbox-display-inner fa fa-check"></span></span>
            <span class="checkbox-label terms-credit">@Editable(x => x.PaymentTemplate.CreditCardTerms)</span>
        </label>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I could just get the value from the form in my action controller but I don't understand why the model binding way of doing it isn't working.

Comment: What do you mean you can select it - you cant check or uncheck it on the screen? or it does not post back correctly?

Comment: I can't check and uncheck it on the screen

Comment: Do you have any javascript that may be interfering with it?

Comment: Check your divs to ensure that nothing in the styling is overlaying the control.

Comment: @Jen are you open to a solution that doesn't use `Html.CheckBoxFor` helper?

Comment: @ekad I can use Request["authorise"] == "on" to check if it is selected or not, but it just seems messy when I'm able to use helpers for everything else.  So this is more to see if someone has a solution to use the helper :)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @stmnmn we just ended up going with <input type="checkbox" ng-model="paymentdetails.authorise"> - couldn't get it working with helpers.

Comment: The problem that the `Html.CheckBoxFor` helper add hidden input with the same name preventing the checkbox from changing its value, I couldn't figure out how to fix that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
The Checkboxfor gets his name from the model.
The problem is:

WHEN 2 different models have the same property,
AND both have a Checkboxfor at the same page, 
the described problem occurs.

in my case, an organisation model (1) and a contactperson model (2) have the same property:

public bool IsActive { get; set; }

SOLUTION
Give them an unique id, in my case:

(1): `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "organisation_active" } )`
(2): `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "contact_active" } )`

Comment: I can't test anymore - but seems likely the issue. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to remove the hidden type input that hindered and always took false to the controller.
I took it with javascript
$ ("input [name = 'Inactive'] [type = 'hidden']"). remove ();
And it worked normally.

Comment: The name = "Inactive" is the my same property.